# UITableViewCell highlight change text field color

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have subclassed UITableViewCell and I have the following code:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (selected)
        self.textField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    else
        self.textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}
```

Basically I'm having only a UITextField in my cell but the color of the label won't change automatically to white so I need some kind of a way to change it on highlight. Any ideas?

Comment: This is almost the correct code. I suggest you move `[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];` to the top of this method, because when updating appearance you usually want to let the parent method finish redrawing everything first, otherwise the parent method might undo the changes you made. If you're still having problems, examine your interface setup and subclass code, this particular piece of code doesn't appear to have anything else wrong.

Comment: Post some more code. The above doesn't seem to have any other problems.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor` and didn't change it in `setSelected:`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that IS the proper way to set the text color on a`UITextField`. But what I'm wondering is: is `self.textField` properly wired up to the correct instance? (via Interface Builder/StoryBoard or in code)

Try adding this code at the top of your setSelected method and look at the console while running your app:

```
NSLog(@"self.textField = %@", self.textField);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

and in your subviews have some thing like this

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

if (selected)
        self.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    else
        self.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor greenColor];


}
```